# How to structure a spring framework web application in 2 separate wars, one for front end (jsp) and another one for business logic?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Due to security reasons our legacy application is split into 2 web applications, one application is for front end and another one for business logic and database interaction, i.e. middle tier.
I am redesigning this application now using the Spring MVC with JSTL.  The tutorial examples are for 1 application.

What should I do to configure this spring application that uses JSP’s in a separate war?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go this way:

- First WAR contains JSP and all Web Components including images, CSS and JavaScript.
- Second WAR contains Spring MVC Controllers and Service/DAO layers. The Controllers are in charge of invoking Service Object and parsing the response to JSON or XML.

With that architecture, your first WAR accesses second WAR services through AJAX calls. That implies intense use of JavaScript: maybe you can use JQuery to help you with that.

Also, that approach let you deploy WARs in different containers. And even the first WAR can't be a WAR at all and it could be even a PHP application deployed in Apache or a plain HTML/JS web page.

Comment: AS I understand the AJAX idea - we use AJAX post and then display the response on the front page. Then the Spring applications is in the middle tier server. For me the deficiency is the need of adding AJAX/JavaScript layer.
Is it possible creating a proxy servlet on the front end that  forwards all Spring requests (i.e. “*.htm”) mapping them to the DispatcherServlet in the middle tier server.
Then overwriting viewResolver in the middle tier server will result in using the JSP on the front server.
At this design using 2 servers instead of one does not affect any development. Is this possible?

Comment: Not tried that, but if your application currently doesn't use AJAX or isn't JavaScript-oriented my suggestion is extremely expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Two main options:

- Provide business logic as a jar and use it from the controllers.
- Provide business logic as a SOA app.

It's not clear to me why the business logic and DB interaction needs to be a separate *web* application, as opposed to library. If they're being deployed on the same server, even less-clear.

If they're being deployed on separate servers, then you're basically making service calls from the "front-end" app into the "API" app. There are any number of ways to do that, could even be EJB-ish, although if you're using Spring, I suspect you're trying to avoid that (although with JEE6, much fewer reasons to).

Comment: This configuration is a legacy configuration, I cannot change it.  Yes, the servers are different.  I would prefer to make a regular jsp/servlet interaction, would it be possible to change just viewResolver in the spring configuration file?

Comment: @anarinsky Maybe, but I don't know how--you're basically trying to communicate with a separate web app, and your access to that app is via normal HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

The first option Dave suggested is also the way we usually do it: Create a [Maven multi-module project](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects) where the business services are built as a simple jar file on which the web tier depends. This way you can have a clean separation between the two layers and possibly reuse the business logic with a different "topping", e. g. a swing client instead of a web app.

Of course, this is also possible when not using Maven - you could keep your source files in separate folders and have Ant (or whatever tool you like) build the deliverables.

Comment: Due to responses I am starting to understand better my options. 
As I understand the idea about SOA and sending the request to the middle tier.  
In this case we will have all Spring application on the front server.  Then the middle tier will simply respond to SOA calls.  For me the deficiency is the need to build a separate SOA layer. 
Please, see further my response to the 3rd answer